# How can i read a qrcode and crop it into a new image in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to use the camera to decode QR Code, get the message inside and crop the original image to get a new clear image of qrcode in Flutter. I find out some packages on pub.dev could do the decode thing but they didn`t reveal the coordinate of the qrcode.

Comment: [this](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_ml_vision) should help

Answer (score 1):

Most packages won't actually capture or store a picture, but rather just read the String that's shown in the QR code. You can use the ones you find, and then display a new QR code based on that String with another package.

Packages to decode (through camera):

- https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_qr_reader
- https://pub.dev/packages/qr_mobile_vision

Packages to encode (display new QR code):

- https://pub.dev/packages/qr
- https://pub.dev/packages/qr_flutter